# Is it possible to stream audio over an NFC connection?

Tags: audio, streaming, nfc

If I have 2 devices that support NFC, can I have one device actively transmit an audio stream over NFC without bluetooth while the other device, either passively or actively receives the audio stream and can play it back on that device? I'm not looking to use NFC to pair two devices over bluetooth, just wondering if it's possible to directly stream audio over that NFC connection. I believe NFC has a max data rate of 424 kbps so that should be sufficient for an audio stream of decent enough quality. I know NFC isn't typically used for that purpose but is it possible or are there some hard limitations of it that would prevent it from being used in this manner?